# Вывести только те элементы массива на печать, за которыми следует четный элемент

Tags: pascal

```
 var
 i, n: integer;
 a: array[1..1000] of integer;

begin
readln(n);
for i := 1 to n do 
begin
read(a[i]);
if a[i] mod 2=0 then write(a[i-1],' ');
end;
end.
```

Почему выскакивает ошибка?

Comment: не помешало бы знать, что за ошибка?

Comment: @mi8882255  уомпилятор пишет что "ОШИБКА ВРЕМЕНИ ВЫПОЛНЕНИЯ"

Comment: Язык Паскаль и без того уродлив, а Вы еще и исходник превратили в кашу. Вот, посмотрите, как пишут те полтора профессионала, которые еще не ушли на пенсию - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xJJpo3jkuWk

Вот еще почитайте - http://avl2.info/index.php?option=com_content&view=category&id=5&Itemid=8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if n > 0 then
  read(a[1]);
for i := 2 to n do 
begin
  read(a[i]);
  if (a[i] mod 2) = 0 then
    write(a[i-1],' ');
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Когда программа проходит первую итерацию, вызов a[i-1] пытается обратиться к индексу массива a[0]. Но его нет, так как массив объявлен от 1 до 1000. Рекомендую сделать проверку, например, что итерация минимум вторая.